# Catkin_make can't find Boost?

Tags: python-3.x, boost, cmake, ros

I'm working on kinetic(Ubuntu 1604) and trying to compile vision_opencv, it's Cmakelists.txt contains `find_package(Boost REQUIRED python3)`.

And I use `sudo apt install libboost-all-dev` to install boost, but it still raises `Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Boost`.

What can I do?

Thanks,

Comment: The file `BoostConfig.cmake` is provided by `libboost-dev` package only since Ubuntu 20.04: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=BoostConfig.cmake. Previous Ubuntu versions don't provide this file. However, CMake itself is shipped with [FindBoost.cmake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/module/FindBoost.html) script, so it should be used instead of possible `BoostConfig.cmake`. Probably, your project disables using of `FindBoost.cmake` script somehow.